# Overflowing to the next DIV

Tags: css, html

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>Pixafy</title>
    <style>
    html { 
      background: url(wp.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.wp.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='wp.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    padding-top: 50px;
    }
        #ldiv {
            vertical-align: top;
            height: 120px;
            width: 40%;
            color:#ccc;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }

        #rdiv {
            vertical-align: top;
            float: left;
            width: 40%;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            height: 120px;
        }
        #ctr {
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 80%;
            height: 150px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            background:url(mid.png) no-repeat center center;
        }
        #container1 {
            vertical align: top;
            width: 80%;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            background-color: #E3E3E3;
        }
        #container2 {
            vertical align: top;
            width: 80%;
            height: 250px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        #text1 {
            align: left;
            width: 80%;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial, Vedana, Tahoma;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #space {
            height: 25px;
            border: 1px solid purple;
            width: 80%;
        }
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 80px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    }
    li {
    float: left;
    }
    ul a {
    background-color: #29281E;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #D6D7D8;
    }
    .clear-both {
        clear: both;
    }
    #text2 {
        width: 70%;
        border: 1px solid #00CCFF;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #btn {
        width 10%;
        border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
    .btnlearn {
    clear:both;
    width:125px;
    height:40px;
    background:#E55D22;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .btnlearn:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #rcw {
        width: 80%;
        color: #BAB8B8;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-size: Arial, Verdana, Tahoma;
    }
    #left
    {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    }
    #right
    {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    }
    #mid
    {
    width:33%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div width=100% style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <div id="ldiv"><img src="pixafy.png" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;" /></div>
        <div id="rdiv">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-both"></div>
        <div id="ctr"></div>
        <div class="clear-both"></div>
        <div id="space"></div>
        <div class="clear-both"></div>
        <div id="container1" style="position: relative;">
            <div id="text1" style="position: absolute; left: 25px; top: 15px;">We are a company of experts developer based in New York City.<br>Partner with us to achieve your business goals through technology.</div>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <div id="text2" style="position: absolute; left: 25px; top: 85px; overflow: auto">Our talented and experienced team has over 10 years of experience developing world-class websites and applications, and we leverage the latest technologies, content management solutions, open source platforms and web standards to solve any challenge.</div>
            <div id="btn" style="position: absolute; right: 45px; top: 100px;"><input type=button class=btnlearn value="Learn More" /></div>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <div id="rcw" style="position: absolute; left: 25px; top: 175px;">Recent Work</div>
            <img src="1.png" style="position: absolute; left: 150px; bottom: 0px;" />
            <img src="2.png" style="position: absolute; left: 400px; bottom: 0px;" />
            <img src="3.png" style="position: absolute; left: 650px; bottom: 0px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear-both"></div>
        <div id="container2" style="position: relative;">
            <div id=left stlye="position: absolute;">
                <span style="position: relative; top: 25px; left: 25px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">Website Development</span>
                <div class="clear-both"></div>
                <img src="wd.png" style="position: relative; left: 25px; top: 40px;" />
                <span style="position: relative; width: 25%; top: 40px; left: 80px; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid green;">Custom websites and easy-to-use content management solutions that are scalable, robust and cross browser compatible. Our team has knowledge and experience in all web technologies.</span>
            </div>
            <div id=right stlye="position: absolute;">
                <span style="position: relative; top: 25px; left: 25px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">eCommerce Solutions</span>
            </div>
            <div id=mid stlye="position: absolute;">
                <span style="position: relative; top: 25px; left: 25px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Mobile Phone Applications</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Outpost**

[image]

I want to wrap it so I can have the similar contents in the next two DIV as well. 
Not sure why is there a tab on the first line and giving me this issue.

Can someone tell me why is it going over to the next DIV?

Please help me resolve this issue.

I would like to make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: 1. You should upload you code to http://www.jsfiddle.net so it'll be easier to help you. 2. You're using inline `style` attributes, which is bad. 3. You're overusing the `absolute` positioning, which is probably the root of this problem

Comment: I agree with @Itay you should add the code to fiddle and edit your question.

Comment: This is a quick markup which will be changed later on.

Comment: It maybe, but the absolute positioning is probably what's making you this problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q9Rvq/ (That's the code)

Comment: I added how I would like it to look.

Comment: I think you need to spend some more time learning to use css properly. To start with learn about things like the padding element. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is overflowing because the element is relatively positioned. As some people have commented you should try not to use too much positioning as it will hinder you from creating layouts that reflow. You could also apply a width to the element to wrap the text.

The HTML for the picture you show should look like this:

```
<div>
    <h3>eCommerce Solutions</h3>
    <img alt="" src="">
    <p>Our team will...</p>
    <a href="">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Css could look like this:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
div img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
div a {
    float: right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LM5MZ/3/

Comment: What about the CSS inside the DIV?

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: Almost there... Thanks! I want the text to stretch down and always stay right of the image and not wrap around though.

Comment: You can just add more margin to the bottom of the image if the box size is static, or you would have to look at an equal height columns method if it is dynamic.

Comment: Or you could add 999px bottom margin and add `overflow: hidden;` to the box

Comment: Thank you... The bottom margin did the job. Question the entire DIV isn't centering on the page but aligning to the left.

Comment: The entire site, I want to center in my browser. Currently the parent div is aligning to left.

Comment: The `<div width="100%" style="margin: 0 auto;">` is not valid html, it should be something like this: `<div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">`

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving you an answer but request you to learn about **Semantic HTML** and **CSS Positioning**. That'd help you out a lot.

Now, as far as this example is concerned, you're over-using CSS Positioning. KISS principle states that the html should be very simple and easy to style. Yours is but is not semantic. I've made it semantic and have then added correct styles to mimic what you want.

New screenshot: [image]

JS Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q9Rvq/3/

Added CSS:

```
#container2 > div h5{
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px 0px;
}

#container2 > div img{
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;

}

#container2 > div p{
    margin-left:55px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:auto;
}
```

Edited HTML:

```
<div id="container2" style="position: relative;">
        <div id=left stlye="">
            <h5 style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">Website Development</h5>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <img src="wd.png" style="" />
                <p style="color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid green;">Custom websites and easy-to-use content management solutions that are scalable, robust and cross browser compatible. Our team has knowledge and experience in all web technologies.</p>
            <span style="position: relative; bottom: 0px; right: 15px;">Learn More</span>
        </div>
        <div id=right stlye="">
            <h5 style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">eCommerce Solutions</h5>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <img src="wd.png" style="" />
            <p style="color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid green;">Our team will collaborate with you to understand your online objectives and goals, using that information to build a secure and reliable web-based storefront.</p>
            <span style="position: relative; bottom: 0px; right: 15px;">Learn More</span>
        </div>
        <div id=mid stlye="">
            <h5 style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">Mobile Phone Applications</h5>
            <div class="clear-both"></div>
            <img src="wd.png" style="" />
            <p style="color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid green;">Our team specializes in developing mobile applications and websites that deliver on quantity, performance and speed.</p>
            <span style="position: relative; bottom: 0px; right: 15px;">Learn More</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the span tag you have which is holding the text that is bleeding over:

```
<span style="position:relative;width: 25%; top: 40px; left: 80px; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid green;">
```

The div, called #left, has a style which sets

```
width:33%
```

so it is a fixed width. the "left:80px" in your span style is forcing the text outside of the fixed width left div. So, just move it to the right, try left: 0px instead.

Comment: you're right its not enough. remove the left: margin style entirely.

Answer (score 1):

In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jandersen/UgtDh/) (don't mind the broken images...) I've only made a slight tweak to the `style` attribute of the `<span/>` tag holding the text which is overflowing.   I replaced `position: relative; width: 25%; top: 40px;` with `margin: 40px 5px 5px 80px;display: inline-block;`   The `display: inline-block` tells the browser to render the element with a box model which is required for the `margin: 40px 5px 5px 80px` attribute to be respected.   This keeps the content within its containing parent `<div/>` tag.

*However*, it's still overflowing the bottom, probably because of the absolute positioning.  If you wanted it to scroll, you could apply `overflow: auto` to that `<div/>` but I don't think that's the look you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the misuse of `position`. It's better in this case to use [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Here is some tidy html taking use of css, padding and a little floating:

**HTML**

```
<div id="BoxContainers">
    <div class="boxes left"> 
        <div class="innerBox">
            <div class="title">Website Development</div>

            <img src="wd.png" alt="" /> 
            <div class="content">
                <p>Custom websites and easy-to-use content management solutions that are scalable, robust and cross browser compatible. Our team has knowledge and experience in all web technologies.</p>
                <a href="" title="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes right">
        <div class="innerBox">
            <div class="title">eCommerce Solutions</div>

            <img src="wd.png" alt="" /> 
            <div class="content">
                <p>Our team will collaborate with you to understand your online objectives and goals, using that information to build a secure and reliable web-based storefront.</p>
                <a href="" title="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes centre">
        <div class="innerBox">
            <div class="title">Mobile Phone Applications</div>

            <img src="wd.png" alt="" /> 
            <div class="content">
                <p>Our team specializes in developing mobile applications and websites that deliver on quantity, performance and speed.</p>
                <a href="" title="">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#BoxContainers {
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    position: relative;
}

.boxes {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    height: 250px;
}
.boxes.left {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.boxes.right {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.boxes.mid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.boxes .innerBox {
    padding: 25px;
}
.boxes .title {
    font-size: 19px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.boxes img {
    float: left;
}
.boxes .content {
    padding-left: 55px;
}
.boxes .content p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9Rvq/4/)**

Take note, there is no inline styling. Avoid using inline styling, even for mocking something up quickly. If you are using css properly, it will be quicker putting your css in a stylesheet and using classes to reuse your styles.